# What Algorithm can be use for task allocation based on location?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, genetic-algorithms

What algorithm can be use for task scheduling based on location? For example there are 100 students and 5 lecturers available.

Each lecturer must get same amount of student using location allocation which is allocation of students depends on the nearest place to lecturer. The system must assign automatically students to lecturer depends on shortest distance between student and lecturer.

```
Student A      Lecturer A 
Student B      lecturer B
Student c      Lecturer C
```

EXAMPLE : Lecturer A can get student c because when compare 3 students address student C is near to lecturer A.

I have done some research on algorithms such as ant colony, bee colony, location allocation but what I can learn from that is it doesn't meet my requirement. So looking for some new algo.  What type of algorithm can be use to solve this problem?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I suggest you learn about [Voronoi cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) first, and understand how such cells are similar to your problem. While Voronoi cells aren't a solution to your problem, you can use it as a starting point for an optimization process.

Comment: @gnat, I have don several research on algorithms such as ant colony, bee colony, location allocation but what I can learn from that is its doesn't meet my requirement. So looking for some new algo.

Comment: @NavhinNair: Gnat is right. You need to edit your question and write a couple of paras about "ant colony, bee colony, location allocation" and why it "doesn't meet my requirement". Some sample data would help too. Good questions get good answers.